# Prove $3 + 5 = 8$ using Quantum Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform, quantum-computer

I am taking Quantum Computing lesson in this term in my School. Our teacher told about Quantum Fourier Transform and its implementation. Then, he did want us to show $3+5$ equals to $8$ with Quantum Fourier Transform.

I thought maybe I can use binary notation for this problem:

$$\mid 1000\rangle = \,\mid 0101\rangle + \mid 0011\rangle.$$

then I try to make QFT to $\mid 0101\rangle$ and $\mid 0011\rangle$. Then I added the result and try to do inverse quantum Fourier transform. But I can't find a solution. I think I do not understand QFT. Then I read a lot of documents about that. I told to my teacher that I do not understand it but he rejected me and said: "you need to understand, think!". I feel very stupid :) Can you please explain to me what my teacher try to tell me, which approach is right to solve that?. Maybe you think that I do not know anything but trust me, nobody in our classroom understands our teacher. I just want to learn how it works. I am curious about it and my teacher just confusing my mind and it will make it more difficult to understand it.

EDIT:
Can it be about Quantum Multiplier?
[Quantum implementation of elementary arithmetic operations](http://cds.cern.ch/record/722038/files/0403048.pdf)

Comment: QM is not even defined if you don't assume that the basic laws of arithmetics are true. You cannot prove that 3+5=8 using QM because QM requires 3+5=8 to be true to begin with. The question is meaningless.

Comment: @accidentalfouriertransform:  the QFT makes perfect sense with or without QM.  No physics is being assumed here.

Comment: Yes, I think you are absolutely right. So do you think our teacher directs us to the wrong way ?

Comment: @Tobi I am sorry. I am not qualified on QM a lot. Can you explain me a little bit more detailed your approach with QFT.

Comment: You can factorize an integer with quantum Fourier transform by using algorithm of @Peter Shor. Maybe you factorize 2^8 as 2^3 * 2^5, and then take logarithm in base 2??

Comment: Does just want you to take the QFT of the two terms on the right hand side and add the QFTs and show that you get the QFT of the left hand side?

Comment: @MitchellPorter Shor's algorithm doesn't work for even numbers.

Comment: If your teacher actually said, *you need to understand, think!* then he is what I would consider a Bad Teacher because, rather than encourage you with a direction to consider, he chose to belittle you by saying you're not thinking about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to think more about what tools and facts about the QFT that you were given in class. For example, did your teacher tell you that the QFT can turn phasing into adding?

[image: Fourier turns phasing into incrementing]

If you phase by the amount that adds 3, then phase by the amount that adds 5...

Comment: Is that image yours? If not, you might want to check on usage permissions and, to be safe, link to the original site.

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes, it's mine.

Comment: @KyleKanos you should delete your comment.

Comment: @CraigGidney What's the point of the image in the context of the answer?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch It shows the QFT turning phasing into adding (well, shifting).

Comment: @CraigGidney Don't see how the answer profits from this ...

Comment: @NorbertSchuch It takes the abstract idea of "phase into add" and turns it into a concrete circuit, and shows it working. It also clarifies details about how to do the phasing, such as the fact that the qubits are not all phased by the same amount. It answers obvious follow-up questions like "Wait, phasing is continuous but adding is discrete in this context... so what does it do when I 'add' 1.5?".

Comment: @CraigGidney I didn't realize that all of this was in this picture!

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Yes, I avoided calling it out on purpose because I didn't want to spoil the whole assignment.

Comment: Our teacher never mentioned about that.